# Selecting lines which match any word from a list with grep

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, csh, tcsh

Can  `grep` pick lines if at least one element from a list of words appeared? For example

```
grep "hello world" file1
```

`grep` must give me all lines which have either the word `hello` or the word `world` or both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep "hello\|world" file1
```

Comment: sorry, but  I have something like "$numbers" not exactly "hello world", so it will not work, any other ideas?

Comment: @lego69: numbers="1 3 5" Somtething like that?

Comment: yes, exactly and now I want to choose all rows which contain these numbers

Comment: or_nums=$(echo "$numbers" | sed -e 's: :\\|:g')

grep "$or_nums" file

Comment: @Anton; you need a semi-colon before the grep (in your comment, not your answer). Without the semi-colon, or_nums is being set in grep's environment, but the shell is not expanding $or_nums in the argument list to grep.

Comment: @William Pursell: Well actually I had a newline - but I couldn't figure out how to preserve it in the comment and format the block as code :(

Answer (score 5):

put your patterns in some file patterns.txt, one pattern per line, and run

```
grep -Ff patterns.txt file1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
grep -r "hello\|world" file1
```

That's a recursive `grep` by the way. It searches recursively for the term "hello world" in file1. It can also apply to a directory like so:

```
grep -r "hello\|world" dir/dir2/
```

Comment: I need also cases when appears only hello or only world

Comment: you can use the above grep by Anton but just add the -r for recursive. something like grep -r "hello\|world" file1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "hello world "| grep -o  "\bworld\b"
```

output is

```
world
```

**or**

```
grep -E 'hello|world' filename
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This only answers part of the question.  Given the input lines `1 hello world`, `2 hello`, and `3 the world-wide web`, all three lines should be returned.  Your answer will not select line 2.  I'm not convinced that the answer should only return the word, either.